# Are there any advantages to Gitlab-CI api triggers vs using the trigger keyword?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In 11.8, Gitlab CI introduced the [`trigger`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#trigger-premium)
keyword to trigger a pipeline in another project.

```
staging:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: my/deployment
    branch: stable
```

Before that, the conventional way of triggering another pipeline was by making a [post request using the api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).

```
build_docs:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline
  only:
  - tags
```

Are there any reasons to continue using the older api method of triggering multi-project pipelines? Are there any advantages to that method vs the newer `trigger` keyword?

Comment: keyword trigger can pass variables and wait for downstream status,But it doesn't work on my 12.8 env, and no error info

Answer (score 1):

Trigger jobs can use only a limited set of the GitLab CI/CD configuration keywords.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#trigger-job-configuration-keywords

If you need to do before_script, script, after_script in the trigger job itself then you need to use the API.